# what different between public static and just static in java

Tags: java

```
public class Contoh {
    public static String publicStatic = "This is static and public";
    static String justStatic = "This is static";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(publicStatic);
        System.out.println(justStatic);
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what different between publicStatic and justStatic

Comment: the default is package scope, public is open for every class, not only those in the same package

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html